# How to modify directive template class name in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, glyphicons

here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tL9hfmpo/).

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <my-checkbox text="apple" status=true></my-checkbox>
    <my-checkbox text="pineapple" status=false></my-checkbox>
    <my-checkbox text="peach" status=true></my-checkbox>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module("app", [])
.directive("myCheckbox", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, ele, attr){
            var iconChecked = "glyphicon-ok-sign";
            var iconUnChecked = "glyphicon-remove-sign";
            scope.icon = attr.status ? iconChecked : iconUnChecked;
            scope.name = attr.text;
            ele.bind("click", function() {
                attr.status = !attr.status;
            });

    },
        template: "<div><span><i class='glyphicon {{icon}}'></i><span>{{name}}</span></span></div>"
    };
});
```

The icon doesn't change when I click it. What have I done wrong? Someone help? 
Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, if you want to change the attribute value, use [`attr.$set`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes#$set), eg

```
ele.on('click', function() { // seriously, why does everyone use bind?
    attr.$set('status', !attr.status);
});
```

Secondly, you should observe the status attribute to update the scoped `icon` as well as manually trigger a digest due to DOM events (like `click`) not doing so

```
var iconChecked = "glyphicon-ok-sign";
var iconUnChecked = "glyphicon-remove-sign";

attr.$observe('status', function(status) {
    if (typeof status === 'string') {
        status = scope.$eval(status);
        attr.$set('status', status);
    }
    scope.icon = status ? iconChecked : iconUnChecked;
});

scope.name = attr.text;
ele.on("click", function() {
    attr.$set('status', !attr.status);
    scope.$apply();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tL9hfmpo/5/

Comment: Really really really appreciate for your awesome answer. You let know not only the problem itself but also some relevant points. Many thanks!

Comment: I found a problem, why all icons are same at the start. In jsfiddle, the second icon should be "remove" style not the "ok" style.

Comment: @nich ah, that's because attribute values are strings unless parsed / evaluated. I've added a check that converts the initial string value into a boolean